# CSS shapes not overlapping next DIV

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, shapes

I'm trying to create 1 shape in CSS (a V-shape). It's working, but when i make the shape negative and place it before another div with a background, I can't get the shape to show "above" the next div with the background-image.

See https://www.bootply.com/dennisgodderie/kBHH7SuoHD
The "content 2" div should get underneath the previous div (red-v-neg) but when I f.e. use margin-top:-100px; it overlaps the red-v-neg div. Even if I use z-index. Or am I forgetting something?

Comment: Your link only leads to an error page. Please add the relevant snippets to your questions instead.

Comment: you could simply add your v-shape IN your content2 div, or use absolute on your shape with positive padding on your content 2 as sir exotic pointed out, link was working fine only for 5 mins for me

Comment: @diegie, does this div have a position of absolute? Otherwise z-index will not work. If that doesn't work, please share your code in your question because the link to your website isn't working.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the answers. I've added the css/html in this post. The div's are not absolute tho. Gonna try that i a few minutes...

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I use for it CSS/HTML

```
.red-v{
    width:0;
    height:170px;
    border-top: 100px solid transparent;
    border-left: 35vw solid #ed4447;
    border-right: 65vw solid #ed4447;
    border-bottom:0;
}
.red-v-neg{
    width:0;
    height:170px;
    border-bottom: 100px solid transparent;
    border-left: 65vw solid #ed4447;
    border-right: 35vw solid #ed4447;
    border-top:0;
    background: transparent;
}
.content{
    padding:60px 0;
    background: #ed4447;
}
.content-2{
    padding:100px 0;
    background: url(http://victus.be/new/img/home-2b.jpg) no-repeat fixed 80% 50%;
}

<div class="red-v"></div>
<div class="content">
  <h1>Content</h1>
</div>
<div class="red-v-neg"></div>
<div class="content-2">
  <h1>Content 2</h1>
</div>
```